# Linux, Gvim lock file

Tags: linux, gvim, perl

I have a file opened with `gvim` and I want to run a Perl script that accesses that file. I get compilation errors, but if I close `gvim`, everything works fine.

> Warning: linker script did not specify CRT1_STARTUP file, default for this device: crt1_extended.o

What could be the cause for this behaviour?

Comment: Please provide the compilation errors you get. This sounds like a file lock issue.

Comment: I'm almost sure that gvim creates the issue, cause if i open other text editor like eclipse, the script is working fine, but my question is,  how gvim puts lock on a file, and how can i modify it to not put that lock file?  Thanks.